# Why can we make outbound operations with ChannelInboundHandlers?

Tags: java, netty

Inside the `channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext c)`from an ChannelInboundHandlers implementation the `ChannelHandlerContext` offers an method like `write()` and `writeAndFlush()`.

These are the given definitions from netty's docs about ChannelHandlers:

- ChannelInboundHandler to handle inbound I/O events, and
- ChannelOutboundHandler to handle outbound I/O operations.

Now my question is why are we able to use write operations inside a ChannelInboundHandler if ChannelInboundHandlers are used to handle inbound I/O events?

I assume that an "inbound" operation(event) would be an operation where the framework receives data from another node. And an "outbound" operation where we send data to another node.

Answer (score 0):

Well wouldn't an `ChannelInboundHandler` be mostly "useless" if you couldn't also for example write from it once you did receive the data on `channelRead(...)` ?

What the definitions means is that `ChannelInboundHandler` methods will be called for inbound events (like receiving data, a channel is accepted etc) whole `ChannelOutboundHandler` methods are called if the user request some sort of action that results in outbound events (like I want to write some data, I want to make a connection etc).

Comment: Yes right so in other words within a ChannelInboundHandler i can both make read & write operations despite the fact that ChannelInboundHandlers are mainly used to make read operations. And can outboundhandlers make also both write & read operations?

Comment: both can make both operations... It's just about for what they are notified